# how to assign value to base class variable in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, inheritance, c#-4.0

This must be a silly question,but I am kind of stuck here.

I have a base class

```
public class classA
{ public string Comments { get; set; }}
```

Another class inherits from the above class

```
public class classB : classA
{
public int classId { get;set;}
public string Comments { get;set;}
}
```

As shown, there are variables with the same name in both the class.

I need to access them specifically.

```
public class AModel{
public classA obj1 { get;set;}
public classB obj2 { get;set;}
}
```

ie, in controller method , I create an object for classB. Here I need to set values for classB variables (not Comments) and Comments from classA.

```
AModel dbModel;
dbModel.classB.classId = "1";
dbModel.classB.Comments = "TEST";
dbModel.Save();
```

Here I need to set value to classA.Comments and not classB.Comments.

How can I achieve this?
Thanks In Advance

Comment: Hi, any suggestions please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example,https://dotnetfiddle.net/6pMuJu, as the variable name is same in the inherited class and the one thats getting inherited, the inherited class variable name gets hidden so change name of one .